# Python CGI - GET form, typing in an address in browser giving the correct page

Tags: python, html, sqlite, cgi

I'm trying to make a website using python with CGI. This website is very basic, all it has is login, logout and display data from a database using sqlite.

I was wondering how would I create a hyperlink to a page displaying a message returned from the database using a GET form with no submit button? The hyperlink would be something like:

```
www.test.com/cgi-bin/test.py?message=id
```

Where the id is equal to an item returned from a list (which has the id and message) from a database. So when I type into the browser say, message=23, it will display that message on a page alone or when I create a hyperlink with the query string message=43, it will display the message with ID 43.

I've looked at this tutorial (Simple URL example: get method part): http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm

But I don't know how I would get rid of the submit button with the values being from the database and appended to the URL. (test.py?foo=bar)

Hopefully I have explained everything clearly.

Answer (score 2):

A URL is a URL. It doesn't matter if you generate it by typing it in, clicking a link, or submitting a form (with method=GET).

```
<a href="http://www.test.com/cgi-bin/test.py?message=22">…</a>
```

---

Update based on the understanding that the question is actually:

> How do I read the query string in a CGI script written in Python?

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
messageid = form.getvalue("message")
```

Comment: Yes, but how would I implement it into my script in which the script reads the query string and displays the appropriate message. If I just created a hyperlink with the above it will just display the same page without retrieving the message from the database.

Comment: Ive tried doing it your way but it still doesn't work unless im doing something terribly wrong.. i have link = "<a href = "blahaha"> then link = cgi.FieldStorage(), messageid = link.getvalue('message') but it returns none

Comment: I've no idea why you are assigning the string  `<a href = "blahaha">` to `link` before overwriting it with the FieldStorage object, but it works for me: http://dorward.me.uk/cgi-bin/test.cgi?message=123